# How can i delete from the table a value from a foreach loop?

Tags: php

I created a table in HTML, and I'm inserting all the information from a specific database table, into this HTML table using a `foreach` loop.

I created a button called delete, to delete a specific row from the database, but I'm having some problems because I don't know how I can delete the table information using a `foreach` loop, because I always use a `while` statement.

I'm doing a kind of MVC structure, but with my own rules, so I got the model and the view, I'm calling all the functions at view.

And I'm doing something like this on view:

```
function fname($array) {
    foreach($array as $key) {
        echo $key['row1'];
        echo "<input type='submit' value='delete'";
    }
}
```

And I made my function on model:

```
function function() {
    connect();
    $show = ("SELECT * FROM mytable");
    $array = db_array($show, 'v');
    fname($array);
}
```

Can you guys help me with an example? Thanks.

Comment: Sidenote: You're missing a `>` in `echo "<input type='submit' value='delete'";` --- `echo "<input type='submit' value='delete'>";`

Comment: Yea i made this code really quickly, i cant post my real code here... but your note doesn't help me, i really want to know how can i delete things from a foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Create a form inside the loop for each row i.e. if it prints out 10 rows it means 10 different forms. While submitting form (clicking delete), send the `row id` as hidden parameter to the controller (in action) while in turns send it to model. Model has the delete query which gets execute and the row gets deleted.

View -

```
foreach($array as $key)
{
    $row_id = $key['row_id'];
    echo "<form action='/deleterow' method='POST'>"
    echo $key['row1'];
    echo "<input type='submit' value='delete'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value=$row_id>";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Controller -

```
function deleterow($id)
{
   $this->model_name->delete($id);
}
```

Model -

```
function delete($id)
{
   $sql = "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id=$id";
   $exe = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this

```
function fname($array){
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
echo $val['FIELD'];
echo '<input name="Z" type="hidden" value="'.$key.'" />';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete"/>';
}     
}
```

I am assuming you are going to make a page where someone can delete something?

You need to echo out the recode name? (this depends on what you are pulling out of the table and fields involved)
The when the delete button is pressed you can act upon hidden field Z